# Чтение и работа с текстовым файлом

Tags: java

```
Дан файл с примерным содержанием:
1 кг
2 кг
1 тонна
3 центнера

На экран должно выводиться 1 кг = 1000г
2 кг = 2000г
1 тонна = 1000000г
и так далее.

Получить цифры из файла у меня получилось. А вот дальше загвоздка. Понятия не имею как вывести конвертированные значения в соответствующем формате. Может быть кто-то подскажет?

Пока что у меня есть это: 

    > public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    >         String s = "";
    >         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\users\\ProblemSet.txt"));
    >         while (sc.hasNext()) {
    >             s = sc.nextLine() + "\r\n";
    >             String a = s.toString();
    > 
    >             String[] str = (s.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim()).split(" ");
    >             int[] intarr = new int[str.length];
    >             for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    >                 intarr[i] = Integer.valueOf(str[i]);
    >                 System.out.println(intarr[i]);
    >             }
    > 
    >         }
    >         }
    >         public void Convertion(){
    >         double mph;
    >         double kmh;
    >         double kn;
    > 
    >         }
```

Comment: Учебный год начался :) - с почином!

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант задай словарь в проге со значениями

"кг" -> 1000

"т" -> 1000000

"мг" -> 0,001
...

и в процессе парсинга по словарю принимай решения:

```
Map<String, Double> convert = new HashMap<String, Double>();
convert.put("кг", 1000.0);
convert.put("т", 1000000.0);
convert.put("ц", 100000.0);
convert.put("мг", 0.0001);

String formFile = "2 кг";
int num = Integer.parseInt(formFile.split(" ")[0]);
String name = formFile.split(" ")[1];
if (convert.keySet().contains(name))
    System.out.println(num * convert.get(name) + "г");
```

Как то так можно. Оберни это в функцию и вызывай ее при выводе на экран.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ и подкрепите его примером кода.

Comment: А как будет выглядеть строка, к примеру, для фунтов или унций?

Comment: convert.put("ф", 0.651); - не знаю сколько там грамм

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

private static HashMap<String, Double> coefDictionary = new HashMap<>();

static{
    coefDictionary.put("кг", 1000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("тонна", 1000000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("тонн", 1000000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("тонны", 1000000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("центнер", 100000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("центнера", 100000.0);
    coefDictionary.put("центнеров", 100000.0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String filepath = "C:\\text.txt";
    List<String> strings = getListFromFile(filepath);
    for(String s: strings) {
        System.out.println(parserString(s));
    }
}

private static String parserString(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    Double coef = coefDictionary.get(parts[1]);
    return s+" = "+(coef*number)+"г";
}

private static ArrayList<String> getListFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String s = null;
    while((s=reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        list.add(s);
    }
    reader.close();
    return list;
}
}
```